# How can I output a json with the new key name from the value in an existing json by jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have an existing json which have a from like this:

```
{
  "arg1": "Admin",
  "arg2": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "arg3": "11",
      "user": "user1",
      "age": 51,
      "arg4": "11"
    },
    {
      "arg3": "22",
      "user": "user2",
      "age": 52,
      "arg4": "22"
    },
    {
      "arg3": "33",
      "user": "user3",
      "age": 53,
      "arg4": "33"
    },
    {
      "arg3": "44",
      "user": "user4",
      "age": 54,
      "arg4": "44"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I try this command:

```
$ cat tmp.json|jq '.data|.[]|{user,age}'
{
  "user": "user1",
  "age": 51,
}
{
  "user": "user2",
  "age": 52,
}
{
  "user": "user3",
  "age": 53,
}
{
  "user": "user4",
  "age": 54,
}
```

What I expect to output is:

```
{
  "department": "Admin",
  "user_age": {
    "user1": "51",
    "user2": "52",
    "user3": "53",
    "user4": "54"
  },
  "year": 2016
}
```

In jq's manual, my request is close to [example 23](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example23).

So I tried to use `from_entries` function

```
cat tmp.json|jq '.data|.[]|{user,age}|from_entries'
```

but get this error:

> **jq: error (at :30): Cannot index string with string "key"**

I know this is because of its format not equal an entry.

So, what should I do to convert to the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from_entries` expects an array of objects with `key` and `value` properties.  You are however generating separate objects with `user` and `age` properties which just would not work.  First of all, you would need to make sure that the properties are in an array, then have the separate key/value pairs for each of the values you want in the array.

With that said, you don't really need to use entries to build out the result, it's not the right tool for the job.  You just want to pull some properties from each of the data objects and add to another object mapping users to ages.  There's many ways this can be achieved, I would use `reduce` to accomplish this.

```
reduce .data[] as $d ({}; .[$d.user] = $d.age)
```

To get your final result, just combine the parts you need into the object you're requiring.  I'm not sure where you got that 2016 from, I'm assuming it's just hardcoded.

```
{department: .arg1, user_age: (reduce .data[] as $d ({}; .[$d.user] = $d.age)), year: 2016}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is as amazing as the `reduce` function!

Answer (score 1):

you can also try:

```
cat tmp.json|jq '{department: .arg1, user_age: (.data|map({(.user): .age})|add), year: 2016}'
```

or

```
cat tmp.json|jq '{department: .arg1, user_age: .data|map({(.user): .age})|add, year: 2016}'
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) explained, [from_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) expects input of the form

```
[ {key:xxx, value:yyy} ]
```

so [Hao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3949473/hao)'s filter

```
.data | .[] | {user,age} | from_entries
```

requires two small modifications to generate the desired `user_age` object:

- the values must be `{key,value}` objects
- the values need to be collected into an array

e.g.

```
.data | [.[]|{key:user, value:age|tostring}] | from_entries
```

(we include `tostring` because the values in the example output are strings)

But since `[ .[]| ... ]` is the same as `map(...)` this could be written

```
.data | map({key:user, value:age|tostring}) | from_entries
```

Here is a complete solution:

```
{
  "department": .arg1,
  "user_age": .data | map({key:.user, value:.age|tostring}) | from_entries,
  "year": 2016
}
```

Sample output

```
{
  "department": "Admin",
  "user_age": {
    "user1": "51",
    "user2": "52",
    "user3": "53",
    "user4": "54"
  },
  "year": 2016
}
```